# Authentication with an id, a password and a coupon code

Tags: authentication, passwords

Could you please teach me the official name(?) of the way to implement authentication with an id, a password and a coupon code provided by the owner?
Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Multi-factor authentication maybe?

Comment: @1615903 Ah, even coupon code? Thank you for your help!